# Is there a way to test if SOAP uses TLS 1.2?

Tags: php, soap, tls1.2

I have got old PHP 5.3 app on old Debian 6. It uses services via SOAP / CURL / file_get_content (POST/GET) and TLS 1.2 will be required soon to establish a connection.

I have successfully recompiled OpenSSL, CURL, PHP and phpinfo say it uses OpenSSL 1.0.2n so we are good here.

Now I want to be sure PHP Soap and file_get_contents uses TLS 1.2 (not old one) so when the TLS 1.2 day will come - all services will be working fine.

I've tested CURL via https://tlstest.paypal.com and it passes.

How can I test SOAP (SoapClient) and stream_context_create+file_get_content to be sure it uses TLS 1.2?

In PHP 5.6 I can force soap to use TLS1.2 with STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT but it's not available in older PHP version.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Or do you know some TLS 1.2 only services so I could test my server against it?

Comment: I ended up using Wireshark per this advice: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142939/determine-ssl-tls-version-using-wireshark Used `tcpdump` on the server and did the capture analysis on Windows. I would only add that Server Helo is the best phase to check for TLS 1.2.